# FileNotFoundException reading JSON file from Assets folder in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, windows-runtime, windows-store

I'm trying to read a `json` file from my Assets folder. I've tried numerous code examples, and all are variations on the same thing.

I feel like I must be doing something stupid, but I just can't see it.

```
string filepath = @"Assets\resources.json";
StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filepath); // error here
var data = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

Every time I run the above code I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` on my app. I've double and tripled checked the file is in the assets folder and there are no typos in my path.

I've also tried this

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/resources.json"));
```

Same error. `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

Screenshot of my Assets folder:

[image: Screenshot of my Assets folder]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the properties of the file (Right click and properties) under **Build Action** have you made sure this is selected as **Content**? Also make sure that **Copy to Output Directory** is set as **Copy Always**. This should solve the problem for you I think.