# Cant see JSON file in project

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio-2013

using VS 2013, C#

I am trying to use JSON file in my project. Using next code (as in sample project from MS):

```
        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/MyData.json");
        StorageFile fileToRequest = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(fileToRequest);
        JsonObject jsonO = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonA = jsonO["Events"].GetArray();
```

As result got this:

[image]

and next step - exception file not found, but it exists

[image]
[image]

Also, if the same code launched with sample project from VS - all its ok.
Code from sample project:

```
        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json");
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();
```

Debugging of this code got:

[image]

So question - why I got exception `FileNotFound`, why this file invisible for my project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh finnally found reason

If you want to use JSON file need to make next:
In properties set `Build Action: Content`, and `Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always`

[image]

Also found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994586/2012219).
Also found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/04/how-to-store-json-data-in-windows-phone-8.aspx) and [this](http://bistw.blogspot.com/2013/07/visual-studio-iis-express-using-json.html) link useful. Maybe it can be helpful for someone.