# ReadTextAsync(file) doesn't work on device

Tags: c#, xml, async-await, storage, device

excuse me for my english. 
In my Wp 8.1 WinRT I created a BackgroundTask.
Debugging on Emulator it works fine, on my device it doesn't.
During debug I see that the problem occurred on the below last line of program

```
StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("TileSmall.xml");
string xml = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

It seems that the command ReadTextAsync() doesn't work on real device.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993849/filenotfoundexception-reading-json-file-from-assets-folder-in-windows-store-app) SO question?

Comment: @ Jeroen Now I try it. Thanks

Comment: I have the same result. I had already set Content on build action. Now I tried to set Copy always in output directory but with the same result. And, on emulator, it works fine...