# Read JSON from file C# UWP

Tags: c#, json, uwp, windows-10-universal, streamreader

Every time I'm trying to read JSON from file I get an error.
If I trying to do it:

```
 JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\DB.json"));
```

or it:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\db.json"))
            using(JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            }
```

I get those error

> {"Could not find file 'c:\DB.json'.":"c:\DB.json"}

If i copy DB.json to the F: directory error is:

> {"Could not find a part of the path 'f:\DB.json'."}

What my problem is?

Comment: And what happens if you put the file in your bin folder and just give the filename to the SR?

Comment: It is working, thank you!

Comment: Find the solution here [UWP JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993849/filenotfoundexception-reading-json-file-from-assets-folder-in-windows-store-app)

Answer (score 3):

Although we can use [File.ReadAllText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) or [File.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx) in UWP apps, but there are some restrictions on the `path` parameter in UWP. Not all the path can be used here.

> Apps can access certain file system locations by default. Apps can also access additional locations through the file picker, or by declaring capabilities.

For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

For your file path like "c:\DB.json" or "f:\DB.json", they can't be accessed in UWP by default. You can use [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847) to gain access first, then add that item to your app's [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457) so that your app can readily access that item in the future.

Besides, to read files in UWP apps, you can refer to [Create, write, and read a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).

As all apps can access application install directory and application data locations by default, I'd suggest you place/store json file in these two locations. If the file is coming with your app and do not need to change, you can place it in your application install directory. To do this, you can add the file in your project and set its **Build Action** as **Content**. However files in install directory are read-only, if you need to change the file later, you can store it in application data locations such as [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241621).

Answer (score 0):

When i'm trying to read a file from JSON i do the following.

first go download NewtonSoft.Json package from NuGet.

and then you can use the following code. (change string to the object you want to deserialize)

```
private static string JsonFile = "myFile.dat";    //your file name

public static async Task<List<string>> LoadFromJsonAsync()
    {
        string JsonString = await DeserializeFileAsync(JsonFile);
        if (JsonString != null)
            return (List<string>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString, typeof(List<string>));
        return null;
    }

private static async Task<string> DeserializeFileAsync(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(localFile);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I implemented it, helped by [Jay Zuo's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37409272/2752308) and [Martin Tirion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38107910/2752308), envelopes all in a single static helper class:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using static Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions;

/// <summary>
/// To deal with the process of ask user permission to read and write in folders
/// outside the App install, data locations and few others, and to remember it for the App lifecycle:
/// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions
/// </summary>
public static class DealAccessFiles
{
    /// <summary>
    /// As a suggestion because Guid.NewGuid() is unique ever; it can be another Token
    /// </summary>
    /// <param></param>
    /// <returns> string </returns>
    public static string TokenForFutureAccessList { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    /// <summary>
    /// As a suggestion; it can be another place, but this is owned by the App
    /// </summary>
    /// <param></param>
    /// <returns> StorageFolder </returns>
    public static StorageFolder LocalForStoreToken { get; } = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    /// <summary>To remember a file or folder; it will use FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(token, fileOrFolder):</summary>
    private static void RememberFileOrFolder(StorageFolder fileOrFolder, string token)
    {
        FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(token, fileOrFolder); 
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// To retrieve the file the next time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token"></param>
    /// <returns>StorageFile</returns>
    public static async Task<StorageFile> GetTokenForFile(string token)
    {
        if (FutureAccessList != null && FutureAccessList.ContainsItem(token)) 
            return await FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To retrieve the folder the next time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token"></param>
    /// <returns>StorageFolder</returns>
    public static async Task<StorageFolder> GetTokenForFolder(string token)
    {
        if (FutureAccessList != null && FutureAccessList.ContainsItem(token)) 
            return await FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(token);
        return null;
    }

    //<summary>To forget a token, you can use this:</summary>
    public static async void ForgetTokenForFile(string token)
    {
        if (FutureAccessList != null && FutureAccessList.ContainsItem(token)) await Task.Run(() => FutureAccessList.Remove(token));
    }

    public static async Task<string> ReadOrCreateTokenFile(string tokenFileName, StorageFolder tokenFolder, string token="")
    {
        var storageFileNameToken = await tokenFolder.TryGetItemAsync(tokenFileName) as StorageFile;
        if (storageFileNameToken == null)
        {
            storageFileNameToken =
                await tokenFolder.CreateFileAsync(tokenFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var customersFolderNameToken = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token)?TokenForFutureAccessList:token;
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFileNameToken, customersFolderNameToken);
            return customersFolderNameToken;
        }
        else
        {
            return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFileNameToken);
        }
    }
    public static async Task<StorageFolder> GetOrPickFolder(
                string folderNameToken
                , PickerLocationId suggestedStartLocation= PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary 
                , string fileTypeFilter = ".json")
    {
        var localFolderToReturn = await GetTokenForFolder(folderNameToken);
        if (localFolderToReturn != null) return localFolderToReturn;

        var picker = new FolderPicker
        {
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation = suggestedStartLocation
        };
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileTypeFilter);
        localFolderToReturn = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        RememberFileOrFolder(localFolderToReturn, folderNameToken);
        return localFolderToReturn;
    }
}
```

Use it like that:

```
  public class CustomerDataProvider
  {
    private const string CustomersFileName = "patients.json";
    private const string TokenFileName = "token.txt";
    private static StorageFolder _localFolder;
    private string _customersFolderNameToken;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> LoadCustomersAsync()
    {
        List<Customer> customerList = null;

        //If it cannot read token, it will create one after you pick a Folder:
        _customersFolderNameToken = await DealAccessFiles.ReadOrCreateTokenFile(TokenFileName, DealAccessFiles.LocalForStoreToken); 

        //After read or create and storing it on FutureAccessList, now it can access the Folder
        _localFolder = await DealAccessFiles.GetOrPickFolder(_customersFolderNameToken);

        var storageFile = await _localFolder.TryGetItemAsync(CustomersFileName) as StorageFile;
        if (storageFile == null)
        {
            customerList = new List<Customer>
          {
              new Customer{FirstName="Joe",LastName="Doe"},
              new Customer{FirstName="Joe",LastName="Doe Jr"},
              ...,
          };
        }
        else
        {
            using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                //Read it, in my case, JSON that I need to share with Windows Forms
                //and VBA(!) Projects
            }
        }
        return customerList;
   }
```

Now, there is no problem to save the file:

```
public async Task SaveCustomersAsync(IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
{
  var storageFile = await _localFolder.CreateFileAsync(CustomersFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

  using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
  {
       //Save the way U need
  }
```