# Can I remember an opened file in a UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I'm using a FilePicker in my app to have the user select a file. But next time the app runs the user has to open it again that way. I want to offer the possibility to open the recent files. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course. Save the path to the file somewhere, like in your application's settings file. Handle failure, in case the file gets moved, deleted, or otherwise becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Please review how to ask good questions on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See my [answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63361644/2752308). First time it asks for permission and will remember the Folder and/or Files for the App lifecycle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using the `FutureAccessList` class. That is a mechanism to remember opened files and/or folders. You have to assign a token yourself to make it unique in your app, but you can use a `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to make it unique.

To remember a file, you can use a method like this:

```
public string RememberFile(StorageFolder file)
{
    string token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(token, file);
    return token;
}
To retrieve the file the next time, you can use this:

public async Task<StorageFile> GetFileForToken(string token)
{
    if (!StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.ContainsItem(token)) return null;
    return await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);
}
To forget a token, you can use this:

public async Task<StorageFile> GetFileForToken(string token)
{
    if (!StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.ContainsItem(token)) return null;
    return await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);
}
```

You can use this mechanism to store a list of tokens with the filename. This way you can provide the user a clue of the files and have a way to open it again.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have access rights to a brokered file directly from a path, so there's little value in saving it. FileOpenPicker is what gives you the access, and it's limited to the specific file it returns. All your app can explicitly is the `SuggestedStartLocation` property on the FileOpenPicker.

The app can make use of `Windows.Storage.AccessCache` to remember the items you had been given access to by the FileOpenPicker. In particular see [StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemmostrecentlyusedlist.aspx).

See [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/)