# How to get a file from FolderRelativeId?

Tags: c#, uwp

Universal Windows Platform API has some restrictions. Also for storage. We can't get file access outside
of library (without file picker). So, I used `StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList`. I wonder how to open a file with that access.

But anyway, I've found this code: `FolderRelativeId` which provides a random ID and file name, such as:

> 6250CF578FDF6C5/Song.mp3

How to use it? Is it for opening a file? Documentation doesn't give some explanations about that.

Comment: [FolderRelativeId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.folderrelativeid?view=winrt-19041) is used to distinguish between items that have the same name. please refer the following to get file with token by using FutureAccessList

Answer (score 1):

`FutureAccessList` is a feature to remember previously opened files or folders:

```
StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    string token = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions
        .FutureAccessList.Add(file);  
}
```

You'll find another example of how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38107910/7252182).

Of course, you'll still need a picker and a consent to be able to open the file in the first place. The API doesn't remove or change the restrictions that apply to the UWP sandbox.